# Python: get OS language

Tags: python

What is a way to get current Windows (or OSX) Locale id on Python 2.x. I want to get an int (or str) which tells what language in OS is active.

Is possible without using WinAPI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the documentation related to the **[locale](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/locale.html)** module in Python 2.6.

To be more specific, here is an example (from the above link) of how to get your system's locale:

```
import locale
loc = locale.getlocale() # get current locale
locale.getdefaultlocale() # Tries to determine the default locale settings and returns them as a tuple of the form (language code, encoding); e.g, ('en_US', 'UTF-8').
```

Comment: This is nice. However I get (None, None) in 2.7.5 on windows. [This bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6203)? It's closed though.

Comment: you can try: `locale.getdefaultlocale()` which outputs for me: `('en_US', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: nice. I should have read the line above the one you linked from the docs. Thanks for adding it to the answer.