# Get current OS language - Python

Tags: python, operating-system, locale, python-3.8

I want to take the current OS language in Python.
For example if english are chosen, I want to get a code (or something like that) and when I change with shift+alt to other language, I want to take the newly changed language code.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: get OS language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387200/python-get-os-language)

Comment: I know the locale library in python, but I notices that when I change from ENG to GR the locale shows again ('en_US', 'cp1252') and not the greek one. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import locale
print(locale.getdefaultlocale())
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html